# Why is an integral treated like a summation?

Tags: integration, summation

$\int^a_b f(x) dx$ is the sum of the areas of infinitesimal strips under the graph $f(x)$. In that sense, the integral is not a continuous sum of $f(x)$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, but rather a continuous sum of $f(x)dx$ between those values, where $f(x)dx$ is the area of each strip. The result of the sum therefore is to give us the total area under the graph between $x=a$ and $x=b$. Why, then, do you so many physics textbooks treat such an integral as the continuous case of $\sum_i f(x_i)$, when this is not a sum of the area?

An example from Griffiths's Quantum Mechanics:

We have a solution to the Schrodinger equation for a particle in an infinite potential well given by:

$$\Psi_n=c_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)e^{-i\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar}{2ma^2}t}\ \  \forall \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Therefore the general solution is given by:

$$\Psi=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)e^{-i\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar}{2ma^2}t}$$

For the case of a free particle (no potential function) a solution is given by:

$$\Psi_k = c_ke^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)} \ \ \forall \ \ k \in \mathbb{R}$$

Therefore the general solution is given by:

$$\Psi = \int_{-\infty}^\infty c(k)e^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)}dk$$

How do we justify the presence of the $dk$?

Comment: Have you looked at the Griffiths hw problem relating the discrete and continuous Fourier transforms?

Comment: An integral is treated like a summation because an integral is a limit of sums.

Comment: The difference is that a free particle is unbounded, so Fourier series no longer work, and instead you need a Fourier integral.

Comment: The author has traded rigour for expedience.

Comment: The Griffiths example is just an example. I see this popping up all over the place in physics and each time I try to justify where the infinitesimal came from. In general, how can a transition from discrete sum to continuous integral be justified?